# How to run a function through each value in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

1. How do I get my buy(i) function to run with each "car in cars" that is repeated in my first paragraph tag?
2. How do I do get the buy() function to run only when clicked once so that if clicked twice, it does NOT subtract the price of a car from the total again, but rather returns(or adds) the amount deducted back to the total.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.total = 2000;
  $scope.cars = [{
      model: "Ford Mustang",
      color: "red",
      price: 100
    },
    {
      model: "Fiat 500",
      color: "white",
      price: 199
    },
    {
      model: "Volvo XC90",
      color: "black",
      price: 190
    }
  ];

  $scope.buy = function(i) {
    $scope.total -= $scope.cars[i].price;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="buy()">{{car.model}}</p>
  <a href="#">
    <p ng-click="buy(0)">{{cars[0].model}}</p>
  </a>
  <p> Money Remaining: <br>{{total}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If money has been subtracted from the value, track it somewhere. Perhaps $scope.subtracted = true/false? Then check against this in the scope.buy() function, I.e `if($scope.subtracted)` - using the result from this, change the operator in your function to `+=` or `-=`.

Comment: The `buy()` function is supposed to substract the value of each car but ALSO the value of one car when clicking on the car ? The logic won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive `ng-repeat` can track the current iteration trough `$index` and you can use that inside the `ng-click` directive to pass in the desired car index.
Note that `ng-click` expects an expression so you will not need to use brackets to evaluate the `$index`.

Allowing to buy only one car of each kind, if I understood correctly, will require you to keep track of what was sold already. In `$scope.history` we can keep the collection of indexes already sold.

I think you want something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <p ng-repeat="car in cars">
     {{car.model}}
     <br>
     <a ng-href="#" ng-click="buy($index)">Buy</a>
   </p>
   <p> Money Remaining: <br>{{total}}</p>
 </div>
 <script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.total = 2000;
     //keep trak of what was bought already
     $scope.history = [];
     $scope.cars = [
       {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red", price: 100},
       {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white", price: 199},
       {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black", price: 190}
     ];

     $scope.buy= function (i) {
       var p;
       //if bought, cancel it
       if((p = $scope.history.indexOf(i)) !== -1){
         $scope.history.splice(p, 1);
         $scope.total += $scope.cars[i].price ;
       }else{
         //else add it to history
         $scope.history.push(i);
         $scope.total -= $scope.cars[i].price ;
       }
     }
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. So how do I get the function to add the price deducted from the total back to the total once clicked again.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect your last wish :)

Comment: This is Perfect. And exactly what I was going for. I did not understand how the indexOf was to be used. I do not get how it works

Answer (score 1):

Set a property to your car to know if it has been bought already or not.

When buying I set the property `isBought` to true. This will also hide the buy button with `ng-if`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.total = 2000;
  $scope.cars = [{
      model: "Ford Mustang",
      color: "red",
      price: 100
    },
    {
      model: "Fiat 500",
      color: "white",
      price: 199
    },
    {
      model: "Volvo XC90",
      color: "black",
      price: 190
    }
  ];

  $scope.buy = function(car) {
    car.isBought = true;
    $scope.total -= car.price;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p>{{car.color}} {{car.model}} - {{car.price}}$</p>
    <button ng-if="!car.isBought" ng-click="buy(car)">Buy</button>
  </div>
  <i> Money Remaining: <b>{{total}}$</b></i>
  <h5>Cars bought</h5>
  <div ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p ng-if="car.isBought">{{car.color}} {{car.model}} - {{car.price}}$</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. So how do I get the function to add the price deducted from the total back to the total once clicked again.